# Unable to target JS generated button within an array with a function, getting "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null" error

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm simply trying to cause a specific button background to change when I click it.
I generated 100 buttons (in the hopes of making a simple game, later on) as an array through a for loop, while assigning an id and a distinct function call (based on the incrementing 'i' value of the loop), and am unable to actually cause the background to change upon clicking, getting the followed error instead
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
at showOptions (brain.js:31)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:15)"

My code goes as follows

```js
var btn = [];
function generateBoard() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var modulo = i % 10;
    var up, forLeft;
    btn[i] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var element = document.getElementById("body");
    //btn[i].innerText = "CLICK ME";
    element.appendChild(btn[i]);
    btn[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    btn[i].id = i;
    btn[i].style.width = "50px";
    btn[i].style.height = "40px";
    btn[i].style.position = "absolute";
    btn[i].style.top = modulo * 100;
    btn[i].style.left = Math.floor(i / 10) * 100;
    btn[i].x = (i + 10) % 10;
    btn[i].y = Math.floor(i / 10);
    document
      .getElementById(btn[i].id)
      .setAttribute("onclick", "showOptions(i)");
    btn[i].innerText = btn[i].id;

    console.log(
      btn[i].id +
        " " +
        btn[i].style.left +
        " " +
        btn[i].style.top +
        " " +
        btn[i].x +
        " " +
        btn[i].y
    );
  }
}
generateBoard();
function showOptions(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;"); //this is line 31
}
```

in console.log I actually get the correct digit as btn[i].id, oddly enough.

the (index.html:15) line of the error is simply

`</html>`

Comment: Have you tried using `addEventListener` rather than setting the `onclick` attribute? The error is because `document.getElementById(i)` is returning `null`.

Comment: So the main problem was indeed the 'showOptions(i)', which as multiple answers suggested changing to 'showOptions(' + i + ')' solved the issue! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.
You should get `body` element with `getElementsByTagName`, which returns array. So pick first element.
Setting onclick attribute should use value of `i` not text `i`.

```
var btn = [];

function generateBoard() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var modulo = i % 10;
    var up, forLeft;
    btn[i] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    //btn[i].innerText = "CLICK ME"; 
    element.appendChild(btn[i]);
    btn[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    btn[i].id = i;
    btn[i].style.width = "50px";
    btn[i].style.height = "40px";
    btn[i].style.position = "absolute";
    btn[i].style.top = modulo * 100;
    btn[i].style.left = Math.floor(i / 10) * 100;
    btn[i].x = (i + 10) % 10;
    btn[i].y = Math.floor(i / 10);
    
    document.getElementById(btn[i].id).setAttribute('onclick', 'showOptions(' + i + ')');
    btn[i].innerText = btn[i].id;


    console.log(btn[i].id + " " + btn[i].style.left + " " + btn[i].style.top + " " + btn[i].x + " " + btn[i].y);

  }
}
generateBoard();

function showOptions(i) {

  document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;"); //this is line 31
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your code, fixing a few issues. I assume you have an element with id `body`, which is distinct from the `body` element, which can be accessed through `document.body`.

```
var buttons = [];

function generateBoard(){
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var modulo = i % 10;
        buttons[i] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        document.getElementById("body").appendChild(buttons[i]);
        //buttons[i].innerText = "CLICK ME";
        buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
        buttons[i].id = i;
        buttons[i].style.width = "50px";
        buttons[i].style.height = "40px";
        buttons[i].style.position = "absolute";
        buttons[i].style.top = modulo * 100;
        buttons[i].style.left = Math.floor(i / 10) * 100;
        buttons[i].x = (i + 10) % 10;
        buttons[i].y = Math.floor(i / 10);
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            // This code is run when the button is clicked
            // Note I am passing the element, rather than an id
            showOptions(this);
        });
        buttons[i].innerText = i;

        console.log(buttons[i].id + " " + buttons[i].style.left + " " + buttons[i].style.top + " " + buttons[i].x + " " + buttons[i].y);
    }
}
generateBoard();
function showOptions(button){
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than assigning and attempting to use an ID attribute you can target the clicked element by referring to a property of the `event` itself. If you were to analyse the `event` ( use console ) you would notice several properties - the `target` allows access to the element itself which helps simplify the `showOptions` function. In this instance you could also simply use `this` to refer to the button itself from within `showOptions` - which would make it even simpler - such as `this.style.backgroundColor='red';`

```js
let bttns=[];

const generateBoard=function( s=100 ){
  const showOptions=function(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor='red';
  };

  for( let i=0; i < s; i++ ){
    /* create a new button and add properties */
    let bttn=document.createElement('button');
      bttn.setAttribute('id',i);
      bttn.setAttribute('data-x',((i+10)%10));
      bttn.setAttribute('data-y',Math.floor(i/10));

      bttn.style.left=( Math.floor( i / 10 ) * 100 )+'px';
      bttn.style.top=( ( i % 10 ) * 100 )+'px';
      bttn.style.width = '50px';
      bttn.style.height = '40px';
      bttn.style.position = 'absolute';
      bttn.innerText=i;

      /* bind event listener */
      bttn.addEventListener('click', showOptions );

    /* add to the DOM */
    document.body.appendChild( bttn );

    /* if it is important to have in an array... */
    bttns.push( bttn );
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(e)=>{
  generateBoard( 100 );
})
```

Adding arbitrary attributes to elements is not best practise - rather than assigning `x` and `y` you should make use of `dataset` attributes instead - so `data-x` and `data-y` would be correct.